# How to install awscli on any linux flavor without having to install python first

Tags: aws-cli

I need to build a script that would install `awscli` on any Linux flavor. I can't expect that python is present on a machine, and the ways to install python on various flavors of Linux differs. How can I install `awscli` without installing python first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "/tmp/awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip /tmp/awscli-bundle.zip -d /tmp/
sudo /tmp/awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Comment: @AniketG - i will be happy to, if you help me understand what you want added. This code is self explanatory and works on a variety of versions and flavors (tested on 10 today). It doesn't have any limitations that I know of. If you take these three lines and run them on a Linux system, it will just work. Let me know if you have any particular recommendations.

Comment: Right sorry. I saw this in the LQP Review Queue, and I went by it rather quickly. You're right. It's pretty self-explanatory. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the distribution's package manager; though you risk obtaining an older version of awscli.

Comment: It's not always true, that was the reason i had to look for a universal way. For example, when i tried `yum install awscli` on RH7, it didn't find that package.